# Problem: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)

Tags: ssh

I cannot connect to the server I get the following error message:

```
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to login-thinking.hpc.kuleuven.be [134.58.8.41] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/emiellanckriet/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/emiellanckriet/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/emiellanckriet/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/emiellanckriet/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/emiellanckriet/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/emiellanckriet/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/emiellanckriet/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/emiellanckriet/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version sshr
debug1: no match: sshr
debug1: Authenticating to login-thinking.hpc.kuleuven.be:22 as 'vsc32452'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:CWFbFs7K9n0JM83sRWimMYY7Ie+f1QJmmvBUS1gVHig
debug1: Host 'login-thinking.hpc.kuleuven.be' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/emiellanckriet/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000)

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000)

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:ebUgOZfhmGQlWbnTz1/IVgyPTlLBSSPN0lqyLpPxSSc /home/emiellanckriet/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Trying private key: /home/emiellanckriet/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/emiellanckriet/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/emiellanckriet/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
vsc32452@login-thinking.hpc.kuleuven.be: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

The public key needed is stored in ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub, however the first debug message say that there is no such file or directory.
I am working on the Windows Subsystem for Linux.
Does someone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was not really a problem, I had uploaded my public key and apparently this still had to be processed on the server. Trying exactly the same the next morning worked for me.